# NSInternalInconsistencyException - Containerview is required

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am still fairly new to objective-c and I am looking for some help figuring a crash on my App.

In my storyboard I basically have a containerview which is using an embed segue to display a UITableView. Basically everything has been working fine for months, but now I am getting this crash whenever the AddPOIViewController is accessed (view does not appear). The builds without warnings or errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboardEmbedSegue perform], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UIStoryboardEmbedSegue.m:18
* thread #1: tid = 0xd9c7c2, 0x0202988a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0202988a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x02afe448 CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    frame #2: 0x019fcfee Foundation`-[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    frame #3: 0x01225438 UIKit`-[UIStoryboardEmbedSegue perform] + 154
    frame #4: 0x010bf07e UIKit`-[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
    frame #5: 0x010bf0f9 UIKit`-[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    frame #6: 0x00c9e2bd UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 605
    frame #7: 0x00c9e5b4 UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 35
    frame #8: 0x00cadab9 UIKit`-[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 36
    frame #9: 0x00cade01 UIKit`-[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 297
    frame #10: 0x00f325e5 UIKit`-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2330
    frame #11: 0x00caa0fc UIKit`-[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 6433
    frame #12: 0x00caa61f UIKit`-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
    frame #13: 0x00caa65f UIKit`-[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 56
    frame #14: 0x010cee16 UIKit`-[UIStoryboardModalSegue perform] + 271
    frame #15: 0x010bf07e UIKit`-[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
    frame #16: 0x010bf0f9 UIKit`-[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    frame #17: 0x0203b874 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    frame #18: 0x00b8c0c2 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    frame #19: 0x00e60c9b UIKit`-[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
    frame #20: 0x0203b874 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    frame #21: 0x00b8c0c2 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    frame #22: 0x00b8c04e UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    frame #23: 0x00c840c1 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    frame #24: 0x00c84484 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    frame #25: 0x00c83733 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    frame #26: 0x00bc951d UIKit`-[UIWindow *sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    frame #27: 0x00bca184 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    frame #28: 0x00b9de86 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    frame #29: 0x00b8818f UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    frame #30: 0x02a8783f CoreFoundation`*_CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    frame #31: 0x02a871cb CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    frame #32: 0x02aa429e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 910
    frame #33: 0x02aa3ac3 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    frame #34: 0x02aa38db CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #35: 0x03a759e2 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
    frame #36: 0x03a75809 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #37: 0x00b8ad3b UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1225
    frame #38: 0x0000206d Pawclub.ca`main(argc=1, argv=0xbfffeed4) + 141 at main.m:16
2013-11-18 12:56:41.093 Pawclub.ca[70486:70b]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'containerView is required.'
** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02afe5e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x020298b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02afe448 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x019fcfee -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x01225438 -[UIStoryboardEmbedSegue perform] + 154
    5   UIKit                               0x010bf07e -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
    6   UIKit                               0x010bf0f9 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    7   UIKit                               0x00c9e2bd -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 605
    8   UIKit                               0x00c9e5b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    9   UIKit                               0x00cadab9 -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 36
    10  UIKit                               0x00cade01 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 297
    11  UIKit                               0x00f325e5 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2330
    12  UIKit                               0x00caa0fc -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 6433
    13  UIKit                               0x00caa61f -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
    14  UIKit                               0x00caa65f -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 56
    15  UIKit                               0x010cee16 -[UIStoryboardModalSegue perform] + 271
    16  UIKit                               0x010bf07e -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
    17  UIKit                               0x010bf0f9 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    18  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0203b874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    19  UIKit                               0x00b8c0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    20  UIKit                               0x00e60c9b -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
    21  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0203b874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    22  UIKit                               0x00b8c0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    23  UIKit                               0x00b8c04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    24  UIKit                               0x00c840c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    25  UIKit                               0x00c84484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    26  UIKit                               0x00c83733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    27  UIKit                               0x00bc951d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    28  UIKit                               0x00bca184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    29  UIKit                               0x00b9de86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    30  UIKit                               0x00b8818f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x02a8783f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x02a871cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x02aa429e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x02aa3ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x02aa38db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x03a759e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x03a75809 GSEventRun + 104
    38  UIKit                               0x00b8ad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    39  Pawclub.ca                          0x0000206d main + 141
    40  libdyld.dylib                       0x0251070d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Program ended with exit code: 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to set breakpoints and find the exact line that crashes?

Comment: `code`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showSelectors"]) {
        self.selectorsContainer = segue.destinationViewController;
         NSLog(@"VC is Set");
    }
}

Comment: Basically it crashes immediately after the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: I get this error if I create a container view inside a view controller and the contained view controller does not have a view. Also, this seems to happen if you try to double nest container views.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the segue is being run more than once. Either your calling perform segue or some other actions is trying to call it again while it's active. There's an internal assertion being hit.

Just don't do that ;)